# CloverETL connecting to Microsoft Access .mdb file

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I am having problems connecting to a local .mdb file. I have seen the following topics, but these didnt solve my problem:

- http://forum.cloveretl.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5093
- http://forum.cloveretl.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=167

My problem is with making the database connection. It doesn't validate the connection and the following error occurs:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The URL ill input is:

`jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=G:\Database.mdb`

Comment: I think i might found the problem. There are 2 ODBC version on my machine, 32 and 64 bit. In the 32 bit version the only driver that is shown is a SQL Driver and not the Access Driver. Someone knows how to install these driver in the ODBC?

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your troubles could be caused by using 64bit Java vs. a 32bit ODBC driver (or vice versa), notice in http://goo.gl/Bs0Ur (the first 'Important'). First, make sure you address this.

Second, it is important MS Access drivers (*.mdb) match your environment. The error message occurs e.g. when using MS drivers which are incompatible with a 64bit OS (your OS being 64bit).

Relevant driver download pages I have been able to find:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23734

Related forum thread:

http://forum.cloveretl.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4663

Hope this helps,
Jan